# Insert an image in LaTeX and create a pdf using: pdflatex file.tex

Tags: graphics, pdf

An image is (attempted to be) inserted using the following script in file.tex:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{/rdata/report/images/buckets.data.csv.png}
\end{figure}
```

Running the following code,

```
pdflatex file.tex
```

I receive this error

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: data.csv.png.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.39 .../rdata/report/images/buckets.data.csv.png}
```

Is there another way to create a pdf from file.tex that would allow for the image file to remain as buckets.data.csv.png?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: (La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to include by using

```
\includegraphics{{/rdata/report/images/buckets.data.csv}.png}
```

The curly braces isolate the correct extension - it hides the other dots from LaTeX.